# S3 -> Redshift cannot handle UTF8

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, paraccel

We have a file in S3 that is loaded in to Redshift via the `COPY` command. The import is failing because a `VARCHAR(20)` value contains an `Ä` which is being translated into `..` during the copy command and is now too long for the 20 characters.

I have verified that the data is correct in S3, but the `COPY` command does not understand the UTF-8 characters during import. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### tl;dr

the byte length for your `varchar` column just needs to be larger.

### Detail

Multi-byte characters (UTF-8) are supported in the `varchar` data type, however the length that is provided is in *bytes*, **NOT** characters.

[AWS documentation for Multibyte Character Load Errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/multi-byte-character-load-errors.html) states the following:

> `VARCHAR` columns accept multibyte UTF-8 characters, to a maximum of four bytes.

Therefore if you want the character `Ä` to be allowed, then you need to allow 2 bytes for this character, instead of 1 byte.

[AWS documentation for VARCHAR or CHARACTER VARYING](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-varchar-or-character-varying) states the following:

> ... so a `VARCHAR(120)` column consists of a maximum of 120 single-byte characters, 60 two-byte characters, 40 three-byte characters, or 30 four-byte characters.

For a list of UTF-8 characters and their byte lengths, this is a good reference:
[Complete Character List for UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Detailed information for the Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS' (U+00C4) can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c4/index.htm).

Comment: why does that letter get converted to `...` though?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/multi-byte-character-load-errors.html

You should use **ACCEPTINVCHARS** in you copy command. Details here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#acceptinvchars

Comment: But the characters are not invalid. I don't want it to destroy the data, I want it to import correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience which some only characters like `Ä` were not copied correctly when loading mysqldump data into our Redshift cluster. It was because the encoding of mysqldump was `latin1` which is the default character set of mysql. It's better to check the character encoding of the files for COPY first. If the encoding of your files are not UTF-8, you have to encode your files.

Answer (score 0):

Using "ACCEPTINVCHARS ESCAPE" in the copy command solved the issue for us with minor data alteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the size of your varchar column. Check the stl_load_errors table, see what is the actual field value length for the failed rows and accordingly increase the size.
EDIT: Just realized this is a very old post, anyways if someone need it..