# How can I replace a character from which I only have the unicode representation?

Tags: c#, unicode, amazon-redshift

I have a string that when displayed in Notepad++ reads:

```
App.xEFxBFxBF35
```

The tocken    EFxBFxBF seams to be some UTF entity that some applications cant handle (for me its redshift).

In Notepad the string reads as

```
App.35
```

How can I remove this entity from a string in c#?

EDIT

In visual studio the string shows in the debugger as

```
"App.\uffff35"
```

**EDIT 1**

At the end it turned out that the column needed to have its size doubled when I inserted non latin characters.

I created the redshift table by looking at the character length of the columns in sql server and directly used that number for the columns in redshift. That was for languages with latin characters, but not with non latin characters.

I found the different length by this  redshift query.

```
select  bit_length('M');
select  bit_length('Б');
select  bit_length('Ö');
```

Gives back 8,16,16

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ef/index.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bf/index.htm may be of interest.

Comment: What data type are you using in Redshift? You should be using `VARCHAR` not `CHAR` - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/multi-byte-character-load-errors.html .

Comment: I am using this version of redhshift and have varchar on it PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two broad options:

- Ensure your Redshift columns are VARCHAR (which [supports UTF-8](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/multi-byte-character-load-errors.html)) of [appropriate size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30724196/34092)
- [Strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)  all non-ASCII characters from your strings before sending them to Redshift