# Redshift CREATE TABLE Error - invalid characters

Tags: join, casting, ascii, amazon-redshift

I've got two Redshift tables.  I can do a select * on a JOIN between them (join is being performed on an id column):

```
SELECT * FROM
table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.user_id
```

However, when I wrap this statement in a CREATE TABLE clause, I get the following:

`error: Invalid characters: code: 8001 context: Only ASCII characters are allowed in fixed length strings. Invalid ASCII char: c3 a1 query: 5183418 location: funcs_string.cpp:1545`

c3a1 seems to be a non-ASCII character.  According to the [Redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html) and [forum postings](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=471698), VARCHAR can deal with up to 4-byte characters.  So I figured this might have been an issue with a column I'm selecting not being properly cast, so I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(255)) 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.user_id
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

I can successfully CREATE TABLE on SELECT * for t1 and t2 independently, as long as I'm not doing a join between them.

I'm at a loss for what might be going on here.  It's worth noting that one of the tables (t2) has a pretty sophisticated set of REGEXP_SUBSTR extracting values from a JSON; I'm not sure if that's relevant, given that the join is failing even when I don't select anything from t2.

Comment: If you were to `UNLOAD` with that query, you could try to `COPY` it in. If it has a similar error, it will show you which line caused the problem, which should be helpful for debugging. See also: [S3 -> Redshift cannot handle UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30724196/174777) You might be able to use just `VARCHAR` without a length?

Comment: What are the data types of `t1.id` and `t2.user_id` ? Is either of them a CHAR data type? Try casting them as VARCHAR if so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comment, this issue is caused by the JOIN condition of the query, rather than the columns in the result set.

What appears to be happening is that when one of the columns in the join is a CHAR data type and one is a VARCHAR Redshift is implicitly casting the VARCHAR data type to CHAR in order to evaluate the join. However as CHAR does not allow non-ASCII characters if there are any in the VARCHAR column this will fail and generates the error shown.

The workaround is to cast the CHAR column as VARCHAR in the join, which should mean both sides of the join are evaluated as VARCHAR.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-char-or-character

> A CHAR column can only contain single-byte characters

Answer (score 2):

What allowed me to avoid the problem was to use the `func_sha1()` function to cast the text join columns to hex.  This is probably costly but it worked for me. `char` vs `varchar` both failed in a join, but `func_sha1` was a work-around that produced results.